# Displaystyle in all equations in R Markdown document entire document

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

is there a way to have equations (inside $$) always \displaystyle without having to type \displaystyle inside each $$? I looked online but couldn't find an answer, only for TeX documents, but not for R Markdown. Thanks !

Nonexample: (test.Rmd)

```
---
title: "Displaystyle"
author: "Stacker"
date: "1/25/2021"
output: pdf_document
fontsize: 12pt
---

$\displaystyle \frac {1}{2}$

$\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^n$

$\displaystyle \int_0^\infty$
```

Beware this task may or may not be possible.

Comment: Please post a small example document for people to work with.

Comment: posted a small document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32824/show-inline-math-as-if-it-were-display-math-and-vice-versa suggests putting `\everymath{\displaystyle}` in the preamble to achieve what you want.  If I just put that into the body of the R Markdown file, it seems to work for me.  For example,

```
---
title: "Displaystyle"
author: "Stacker"
date: "1/25/2021"
output: pdf_document
fontsize: 12pt
---

\everymath{\displaystyle}

$\frac {1}{2}$

$\displaystyle \frac {1}{2}$

$\sum_{i=0}^n$

$\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^n$

$\int_0^\infty$

$\displaystyle \int_0^\infty$
```

produces duplicates of each equation.  To restore the default, just include `\everymath{}`.

*Edited to add:*  One limitation of this approach:  MathJax doesn't support `\everymath`, so this only works in formats like `pdf_document` that use LaTeX as an intermediate.  If you want the same behaviour in `html_document`, you'll need to do something else.